# Spring Data Repositories - Find where field in list and other is normal

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I read official spring doc (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

```
In      findByAgeIn(Collection<Age> ages) … where x.age in ?1

NotIn   findByAgeNotIn(Collection<Age> ages) … where x.age not in ?1
```

My error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.project.dao.DeviceRepository.findBySiteAndTypeIn(Lcom/project/model/Site;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;
```

I'm trying to use spring CrudRepository with a find Device where types in list:

```
public interface DeviceRepository extends CrudRepository<Device, Long> {

    List<Device> findBySiteAndTypeIn(Site site, List<String> types);

}
```

This code is OK but without list:

```
public interface DeviceRepository extends CrudRepository<Device, Long> {

    List<Device> findBySiteAndType(Site site, String type);

}
```